# shell script for finding the unix noun phrase

Tags: linux, bash, unix, shell

one entry in the on database is:

```
LPE-1*story#1/1 of pearl#1/2*historia de la perla*storia della perla* histoire de la perle* história da pérola*istoria perlei*TOPIC
```

The fields are separated by stars, *. They are:

```
sentence ID|English NP|Spanish translation|Italian translation|French translation|Portuguese translation|Romanian translation|Semantic relation
```

The English NP field has the following format:

```
noun1#sense/i [preposition] noun2#sense/j
```

where i and j can be either 1 or 2 indicating the position of the semantic argument in the NP instance (note that the preposition might be missing). For example, in the NP instance chair#1/2 arm#1/1 which encodes a part-whole relation (P-W), the noun chair indicates the whole (and thus is labeled as 2), and the noun arm encoded the part (and is labeled as 1).

**Problem:**

Write a shell script containing a combination of UNIX and AWK commands that will give the answer to the following questions. The shell script should be executed only once and output (to standard output, unless mentioned otherwise):

1. the number of English NP instances in the file;
2. the number of unique English NPs (consider for this the entire field $2);
3. the list of unique semantic relations considered in this database (store it in "sr.uniq.txt");
4. the frequency of each semantic relation in the database with the following format: Semantic_relation  frequency 
   (store this in "sr-freq.txt");

How to do for question 2,3,4

Comment: Is this a homework assignment?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: awk has associative arrays, and the keys in an associative array will be unique.

Comment: Related: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/55075)